# NodeJS Ajax requests working exactly seven times

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, electron

I'm currently learning JavaScript / NodeJS / electron, and I want to build a small presenter-app to remotely control powerpoint-presentations.

I've setup a server using electron like this:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const robot = require("robotjs");
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow
} = electron;

var mainWin = null;
var contentString;

app.on('ready', function() {
  mainWin = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  });

  contentString = "";

  // Remove Menu-Bar
  mainWin.setMenu(null);

  const port = 3000;

  var app = express();
  app.use(cors());

  app.post('/remote/forward', function(request, response, next) {
    var ip = getRemoteIP(request);
    log(mainWin, "presenter - forward");
    robot.keyTap("right");
  });

  app.post('/remote/backward', function(request, response, next) {
    var ip = getRemoteIP(request);
    log(mainWin, "presenter - backward");
    robot.keyTap("left");
  });


  app.listen(port, function() {
    log(mainWin, 'server listening on port ' + port);
  });
});


function log(mainWin, text) {
  contentString += getFormattedDate() + " " + text;
  contentString += "<br />";
  mainWin.loadURL("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(contentString));
}
```

I call these with two js-functions:

```
function sendForwardRequest() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
         blob: {action:"forward"}
     },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://192.168.2.110:3000/remote/forward',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("some error in fetching the notifications");
    }
  });
}

function sendBackwardRequest() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
         blob: {action:"backward"}
     },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://192.168.2.110:3000/remote/backward',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("some error in fetching the notifications");
    }
  });
}
```

I'm sure that this solution is quite miserble, as I said, I'm currently learning this. My question now is: This works for exactly seven times. After that, I have to reload my clients browser. How can I fix this? Also, what would be a better solution for the requests? I'd like to have only one app.post()-method and use the given  post-parameters instead. Last question: What could be a nicer method for the logging? I'd like to append content to my window instead of having to reload the whole string each time.

Thank you very much!

Comment: just to simplify, you don't need a `POST`, use `GET`. also why are you sending `data: { blob: .. }` ? you can tell its forward or backward by url

Comment: @Jag as I said, I think it would be nicer to use one url for this task and specify the kind using the data. But you're right of course, if you want different urls for each function.

Comment: Note: I just changed the requests to GET, which allows me to call the requests only once each.. I just changed from app.post to app.get and set the types to get. Do I have to do something additionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the minified version of your code. try and see if it still only fires 7 times

```
/* Server side */

  // instead of two app.post functions, use this one
  app.get('/remote/:key', function(request, response, next) {
    var ip = getRemoteIP(request);
    log(mainWin, "presenter - " + request.params.key);
    robot.keyTap(request.params.key);
    response.send(request.params.key + ' key pressed');
  });

/* Client Side */

function sendKey(key) {
  return $.get('http://192.168.2.110:3000/remote/' + key)
}

// to send right key
sendKey('right').done(function(response) { /*success*/ }).fail(function(error) { /*error*/ });
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This works once, after that, I have to reload the page. After the reload, the code that I created in your /*error*/-part is executed twice. Do you have an idea what the problem there might be?

Comment: Edit: nevermind, it was that I needed a response, just like you edited! Thank you very much!